# Php color replace on image

Tags: php, replace, colors

I have this script that replaces black or white color with another color as chosen by the user, works ok however on certain colors (purple background green writing) it leaves a white pixelated border around the letters?
I cant figure out what to do?
see it here - http://marijasorganicpantry.com.au/imagephp.php

```html
<?php
ob_start();
 $txtcolor=$_REQUEST['text1'];
 $r1txt=hexdec(substr($txtcolor,0,2));
    $g1txt=hexdec(substr($txtcolor,2,2));
 $b1txt=hexdec(substr($txtcolor,4,2));
 
 $backcolor=$_REQUEST['back1'];
 $r1back=hexdec(substr($backcolor,0,2));
    $g1back=hexdec(substr($backcolor,2,2));
 $b1back=hexdec(substr($backcolor,4,2));
 $imgname="demo_the-crown-prints_work-hard_5x7.jpg";
 
 $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgname);
 $w = imagesx($im);
 $h = imagesy($im); 
 $gd = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
 imagecopyresampled($gd, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w, $h);
 imagefilter($gd, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE,$r1txt,$g1txt,$b1txt); 

 for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++) 
 {
  for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++)
   {
    $rgb = imagecolorat($gd, $x, $y);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
    
    if ($r==255 and $g==255 and $b==255)
    { 
    $pixelColor=imagecolorallocatealpha($gd,$r1back,$g1back,$b1back,10);
    imagesetpixel($gd,$x,$y,$pixelColor); 
    }
   }
 }
 
imagejpeg($gd,NULL,100);
$outputBuffer = ob_get_clean();
$base64 = base64_encode($outputBuffer);
echo '<a id="downloadimage" style="text-decoration:none;" download>
 <img id="image2" width=150 height=250 src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$base64.'" />
 <li style="padding-top:7px;textalign:center;display:block;border-radius:10px;background-color:royaleblue;height:30px;width:100px;">download</li></a>'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the original image the letters have a border that it is not a perfect black, so the color is not

```
R = 0
G = 0
B = 0
```

I have change a little bit your original code to avoid unnecessary steps. Is this what do you need?

```
<?php
ob_start();
$txtcolor="20FF00";
$r1txt=hexdec(substr($txtcolor,0,2));
$g1txt=hexdec(substr($txtcolor,2,2));
$b1txt=hexdec(substr($txtcolor,4,2));

$backcolor="FF0ED9";
$r1back=hexdec(substr($backcolor,0,2));
$g1back=hexdec(substr($backcolor,2,2));
$b1back=hexdec(substr($backcolor,4,2));
$imgname="demo_the-crown-prints_work-hard_5x7.jpg";

$gd = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgname);
$w = imagesx($gd);
$h = imagesy($gd);
for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++) 
{
    for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++)
        {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($gd, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

            if ($r>200 && $g>200 && $b>200)
            {   
                $pixelColor=imagecolorallocate($gd,$r1back,$g1back,$b1back);
                imagesetpixel($gd,$x,$y,$pixelColor);                   
            } else {
                $pixelColor=imagecolorallocate($gd,$r1txt,$g1txt,$b1txt);
                imagesetpixel($gd,$x,$y,$pixelColor);
            }
        }
}

imagejpeg($gd,'simpletext.jpg', 100);
imagepng($gd,'simpletext.png', 0);
?>
```

I have saved the result on files to let you see the difference of quality between the imagejpeg and imagepng

Comment: thanks for that, i have taken out most of the greyscale to try and make the image true black and white however i still have some grey spots in the image so they are showing as white, how can I add the extra grey colors to the code so that they get converted too? i have tried if ($r==255 and $g==255 and $b==255 || $r==212 and $g==212 and $b==212 || $r==224 and $g==224 and $b==224 ) but its not working what is wrong with the code?

Comment: If you want to assume that the original image is only white and black just try to do something like that if ($r!==0 || $g!==0 || $b!==0). In your code you forgot a lot of possible combinations ;)

Comment: I can see lots of grey spots when i zoom in so i thought maybe if i can get their values and add them all in it could at least get a little better quality and get rid of some of the spots :) how can I add more shades to the code? i am stuck

Comment: If you use this ($r!==0 || $g!==0 || $b!==0) you are selecting every pixels that it is not perfect white and you can consider it black. Probably this result could be fine for you (if you want to keep simple). Otherwise another solution is work with edges like $r<100 ... is white otherwise is black. There are better solutions but I am trying to keep it simple.

Comment: I mean use ($r!==0 || $g!==0 || $b!==0) instead ($r==255 and $g==255 and $b==255) on your original code

Comment: ok i understand now thank you :) i try to put that into the code where i had the original ($r==255 and $g==255 and $b==255) but it makes everything become one color?

Comment: Because I am stupid! 255 255 255 mean white, not black... What a horrible mistake I have made (sorry) :D   Use ($r!==255 || $g!==255 || $b!==255)

Comment: The general idea still the same ;)

Comment: Thats ok so grateful for your help :) I tried that too but now the black part changes to the color that i select for white and the background stays white?

Comment: thanks tried it with (!($r!==255 || $g!==255 || $b!==255))  but stil getting white dots around the text?

Comment: I have changed the first answer, I have written code that could be useful to you. Have a look

Comment: WOW you are AWESOME!! it works perfectly! thank you so much for your help i am so grateful! Bless you :)

Comment: I tried but i need a rep of 15 before it will let me do that, when i get my rep up I will come back and do that for you :)